# Curvature of Lobatchevski space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the Lobachevsky plane defined as

$$\mathbb{R}^2_+ = \left\{{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2};y>0}\right\}$$

with the metric given by $$g_{11} = g_{22} = \frac{1}{y^2}, g_{12} = 0$$

Calculate the curvature at each point.

The only thing I think I could do is to apply this two formulas:

$$K = \frac{R_{1212}}{g_{11}g_{22}-g^2_{12}}$$

where $$R_{klij} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d^2}{dx^jdx^k}g_{il} + \frac{d^2}{dx^idx^l}g_{jk} - \frac{d^2}{dx^jdx^l}g_{ik} - \frac{d^2}{dx^idx^l}g_{jl} + g_{rs}Γ^r_{jk}Γ^s_{il} - g_{rs}Γ^r_{jl}Γ^s_{ik} )$$

But I am not sure, anyone could help me? Thakyou very much!

Comment: Yes just apply it.

Comment: But using that, I get  $$K =  \frac{\frac{-12}{y^4}}{\frac{1}{y^4}} = -12$$ when it should be -1

Answer (score 2):

It pays off to show in general that the curvature of $$\frac{{\rm d}x^2+{\rm d}y^2}{h(x,y)^2}$$is $K = h(\triangle h) - \|\nabla h\|^2$. For $h(x,y)=y$ this gives $K=-1$ as expected.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? Where I can find this formula of the curvature? what means $$△$$ and $$h(△h)$$ I think that $$∇$$ means divergence of  $$h$$      it´s true? sorry but I haven´t seen this notation before...

Comment: All the notation is standard in multivariable calculus: $\nabla$ means "gradient" and $\triangle$ means Laplacian. The term $h(\triangle h)$ is a product of two functions. In books about curves and surfaces, when one proves Gauss' Theorema Egregium, one usually establishes the formula $$K=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\left(\frac{E_y}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_y+\left(\frac{G_x}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_x\right)$$for orthogonal parametrizations, and it follows from this one.

Comment: where can I find an explanation of how to get this formula? $$K = h(△h) - \left\|{h}\right\|^2$$

Comment: Plug the given coefficients in the formula from my previous comment.

Comment: could you explain it a little bit? I can´t see it obviously